# BackboneJS collection add event fired on multiple collections

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am running into an issue where I'm adding to a collection, `CollectionA`, where `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` are listening for an add event.  However, an add event is triggered for both collections when adding to `CollectionA`.  `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` are basic collections that extend `Backbone.Collection` and only setting a url.

View Definitions

```
ModelViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    render : function() {
        var self       = this;
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));

        var collectionB     = new CollectionB();
        var collectionViewB = new CollectionViewB();
        collectionB.fetch({
            self.$el.append(collectionViewB.render().el);
        });

        return this;
    },
    ...
});

CollectionViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
       this.collection.on('add', this.renderOne, this);
    },
    ...
    render : function() {
       this.collection.forEach(this.renderOne, this);
       return this;
    },

    renderOne : function(model) {
        console.log('Added to Collection A');

        var view = new ViewA({ model : model });
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
        return this;
    }
});

CollectionViewB = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
       this.collection.on('add', this.renderOne, this);
    },
    ...
    render : function() {
       this.collection.forEach(this.renderOne, this);
       return this;
    },

    renderOne : function(model) {
        console.log('Added to Collection B');

        var view = new ViewB({ model : model });
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Here's how I'm starting off the cascade of these events...

```
var collectionA = new CollectionA();
var modelViewA = new ModelViewA({
    model : collectionA.at('some id');
});

$('body').append(modelViewA.render().el);
$('body').empty();

var collectionViewA = new CollectionViewA({ collection: collectionA });
$('body').append(collectionViewA.render().el);
collectionViewA.add([{...}]);
```

This code will output the initial view correctly with the modelView. Then it will properly render the `collectionViewA`, however when I trigger the add event it will try to add to `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` so the console will show the following for each time the add event is called

```
Added to Collection B
Added to Collection A
```

It will also attempt to render `Collection B`, but throws an error because the template is not given a model.

Let me know if this is way too confusing and I can try to flush out this description a bit more.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Why, in your render method of `ModelViewA`, do you create a `CollectionB` instance  that fetches?

```
    var collectionB     = new CollectionB();
    var collectionViewB = new CollectionViewB();
    collectionB.fetch({
        self.$el.append(collectionViewB.render().el);
    });
```

That doesn't even parse.  Are you sure you didn't accidentally edit out the anonymous success function? First let me suppose that's not quite what your code shows.
That is, is it supposed to be something like:

```
    collectionB.fetch({
        success: function(){
           self.$el.append(collectionViewB.render().el);
        }
    });
```

?

Let's go with that.

So when the `ModelViewA` is rendered, *obviously* `collectionB` is going to fetch something and then `collectionViewB` is going to render because *that's what you told it to do*.  Now would cause you to render `ModelViewA`s?

```
CollectionViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
       this.collection.on('add', this.renderOne, this);
    }, ...
```

```
renderOne : function(model) {
    console.log('Added to Collection A');

    var view = new ViewA({ model : model });
    this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    return this;
}
```

what's this `ViewA`?  could that also refer to `ModelViewA`?

If so, we might guess as to what is happening:

Your `CollectionViewA` instance renders a `ModelViewA` instance on every addition. Every rendering of a a `ModelViewA` instance creates a `CollectionB` instance (`collectionB`) and a `CollectionViewB` instance (`collectionViewB`), and the `collectionB` fetch has a success method which renders `collectionViewB`. If `collectionB` has any models, for every model, it successfully logs to the console  "Added to Collection B" before attempting to render ViewB instances, which, if I understand you correctly, fail (which might be why you only have one "Added to Collection B" message.

Now as to why the console logs are in reverse order... I'm still trying to figure that one out.  Maybe I missed something.

In any case... This situation is not ideal. I'm not sure what I could say to improve your code, though.  Calling `fetch` from `render` seems to me like you're specifying to much to do in your render code.  I'm not even sure you knew that `fetch` was there to begin with.

Comment: Yeah you were right about those issues in the code. The reason why there is a fetch in the render is because it's kind of like a widget. I want to add this widget to multiple places, but only have to call it in this one area.

I was able to find the root cause of the issue though, it seems to be because they're extending the same base class, that isn't Backbone.Collection.  By changing one of them to Backbone.Collection the issue goes away.

Note... don't use a Base class to add things, apparently it will throw the add for all things extending it rather than the child class.